# Does NRoots own an abstract counterpart? If not, can we write one?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, numerics, polynomials, matlab

We know when solving linear algebra equations, despite its abstract syntax, `LinearSolve` is much faster compared to `Solve`:

```
n = 1000;
m = DiagonalMatrix@RandomReal[{1, 2}, n];
b = RandomReal[1, n];
sol1 = LinearSolve[m, b]; // AbsoluteTiming
x = Table[Unique[], {n}];
sol2 = Solve[m.x == b, x]; // AbsoluteTiming
Last /@ First@sol2 == sol1
```

> ```
> {0.124800, Null}
> {1.216800, Null}
> True
> ```

I wonder if `NRoots` owns such a counterpart, too?

…To be honest, I came across this problem because a friend of mine claimed that a *matlab* function [`roots()`](http://radio.feld.cvut.cz/matlab/toolbox/mathlib/cppmathug/matlab11.html) is one order of magnitude faster than `NRoots[]`. The following is the comparison between `NRoots` and `roots`.

`NRoots` in *Mathematica 9.0.1*:

```
n = 10; m = 10000; list = RandomInteger[{1, 100}, {m, n + 1}];
equations = list.x^Range[0, n];
NRoots[#, x] & /@ equations; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {7.984318, Null}

[image: NRoots in Mathematica 9.0.1]

`roots` in *Matlab R2014a*:

```
 clear;clc;
 n = 10;
 m = 10000;
 lst=randi(100,m,n+1);
 tic;
 for i=1:m
     roots(lst(i,:));
 end
 toc
```

> Elapsed time is 0.756003 seconds.

[image: roots in Matlab R2014a]
Given the performance difference between `LinearSolve` and `Solve`, I believe if the analysis for the structure of polynomial is eliminated, *Mathematica* will have the same speed.

If such an internal function doesn't exist, can we have a self-made one **that eliminates the preprocessing**? Anyway, though I almost don't know the syntax of *Matlab*, the definition of `roots()` seems to be simple so I think it won't be that hard to implement the same algorithm in *Mathematica*.

---

OK, since the target of this question hasn't been completely achieved (`NRoots` owns 3 methods, currently only `"CompanionMatrix"` is implemented), let me add something to try to draw more attention. You remember this?:

[image]

It's said that Sam Derbyshire spent 4 days for [a similar one](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/roots/), while the above image only takes me no more than 3 minutes in my old 2GHz laptop with `roots[]` that [chyaong](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2090/chyaong) showed in his answer below:

```
(* I modified chyaong's roots[] a little for this specific task. *)
modifiedroots[c_List] := 
  Block[{a = DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1., Length@c - 1], -1]},
         a[[1]] = -c;
         Eigenvalues[a]];

s = 1000;
l = ConstantArray[0., {s + 1, s + 1}];

l[[#, #2]] += 1. & @@@ 
   Round[1 + s Rescale@
       Function[z, {Im@z, Re@z}, Listable]@
        Flatten[modifiedroots /@ Tuples[{-1., 1.}, 18]]]; // AbsoluteTiming

ArrayPlot[UnitStep[80 - l] l, ColorFunction -> "AvocadoColors"]
```

> ```
> {161.737000, Null}
> ```

<strike>Let's ignore the fact that my image is only degree 19.</strike>

This is not the end, according to my simple test (I simply add different `Method`s to the 2nd sample of this post), the `"Aberth"` method is probably more efficient than the `CompanionMatrix` inside `NRoots`, so if it's implemented in an abstract form, the above image will likely to be done in a even shorter time!

Comment: (1) `NRoots` takes a `Method` option. The three documented possibilities are `"Aberth"`, `"JenkinsTraub"`, and `"CompanionMatrix"`. (I do not know if there are undocumented possibilities). From what I could see, the third of those possibilities should be similar to what `roots()` does.

Comment: (2) I confess I fail to see an analogy to `Solve`/`LinearSolve`, unless `NRoots` plays the role of `LinearSolve` with `Roots` being the "more general" function (insofar as it handles exact and symbolic input). I suppose one could go from the coefficient list and directly form a companion matrix and invoke `Eigenvalues`. Would that be faster or as reliable? I don't know.

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my question, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want improve my question if possible.

Comment: I don't know exactly (I didn't vote one way or the other) but I can say a bit about things I thought could bear improvement. One issue is that it could have been phrased differently, maybe as "Are there different methods of `NRoots` that could have impact on performance vs. quality?" As I noted in a comment, the analogy to `Solve/LinearSolve` is just not clear to me. A bigger issue, in my mind, is that there is no clear example where `NRoots` is seen to perform relatively badly as compared to `roots()`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That sounds reasonable. Question edited. (Thanks for the test from [Amita](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/24915/amita)!)

Comment: `list.x^Range[0,n]==x^Range[0,n].Transpose@list`

Comment: @chyaong Yeah, `list.x^Range[0, n]` is simper, but Amita has chosen the latter and take the screenshot, so let it be, anyway it's not the main issue here :)

Comment: @xzczd, 根据你编辑后的代码，Mathematica 10.02的NRoots的速度大概是Mathematica 9的4倍多；用我答案中的roots，速度和matlab的roots差不多

Comment: Translation for the comment of @chyaong: _According to your new-added code, `NRoots` in v10.0.2 is more than 4 times as fast as that in v9.0.1. The `roots[]` in my answer has similar performance as `roots()` of matlab._ Well, that's interesting.

Answer (score 9):

Translated that `roots()` function from Matlab code to Mathematica, about 4 times faster than `NRoots` .

```
Clear["`*"];
n=2000;
m=RandomReal[1,{n,10}];
res1=x/.(ToRules@NRoots[FromDigits[#,x]==0.,x]& /@ m);//AbsoluteTiming
(*-------------------------------*)
roots[c_List]:=Block[{a},
 a=DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1.,Length@c-2],-1];
 a[[1]]=-Rest@c/First@c;
 Eigenvalues[a]
];

res2=Join @@ roots /@ m;//AbsoluteTiming

Union@Chop[Sort@res1 - Sort@res2]
```

Output:

> {1.080062, Null}
>
> {0.241012, Null}
>
> {0}

```
n = 10;
m = 10000;
list = RandomReal[{1, 100}, {m, n + 1}];
equations = list.x^Range[0, n];
res1 = x /. (ToRules@NRoots[#, x] & /@ equations); // AbsoluteTiming
res2 = Join @@ roots /@ Reverse /@ list; // AbsoluteTiming
Sort@res1 - Sort@res2 // Chop // Union
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you try this with modestly higher degree (so preprocessing time does not dominate) you will see comparable timings. E.g with `n = 100;
m = RandomReal[1, {n, 100}];` Also the residuals from the `NRoots` result will be smaller.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yeah, and eliminating the preprocessing is the target of this question. I just edited the question and made this part clearer (I think).

Comment: Ah. No, I'm not aware of a lower level function that extracts numeric roots from a list of polynomial equations.

Comment: As for the higher degree case I had mentioned, here is a plausible test. `n = 100;
m = 100;
list = RandomReal[{1, 100}, {m, n + 1}];
equations = list.x^Range[0, n];
res1 = x /. (ToRules@NRoots[#, x] & /@ equations); // AbsoluteTiming
res2 = Join @@ roots /@ Reverse /@ list; // AbsoluteTimingl`

Comment: Any plan to implement the other 2 method of `NRoots[]`? Though I admit this question is motivated by my competitive mood against _Matlab_, now its target is to get the counterpart of `NRoots[]` anyway :)

Comment: @xzczd, this is a bit late, but: as I show [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/143181), there's a built-in *undocumented* routine to compute the (Frobenius) companion matrix (which can then be passed to `Eigenvalues[]`). For Aberth's method, I have a barebones implementation [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1646447); Jenkins-Traub, however, is much more complicated and finicky to implement properly.

Comment: Very nice. On my machine ``roots2 = Eigenvalues[NRoots`CompanionMatrix[Reverse[#]]]&;`` is about twice as fast.

Answer (score 5):

We can also using [GSL](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) via LibraryLink, almost ten times faster than before.

```
LaunchKernels[];
ParallelMap[roots, Tuples[N@{-1, 1}, 15]]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {1.1, Null}

```
gslRoots@Tuples[N@{-1, 1}, 15]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.12, Null}

It only takes about 3 minutes to calculate the roots of all polynomial equations of degree 24 with a coefficient of ±1.

[image]

For visualization, it's better to find the location of each roots within the image matrix in C code, instead of calculating all roots in Mathematica. It takes about 150 seconds to generate a 100 million pixel image.

[image]

Mathematica code:

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
$CCompiler={"Compiler"->CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler,"CompilerInstallation"->"C:/msys64/mingw64","CompilerName"->"gcc.exe","CompileOptions"->"-Ofast"};

LibraryUnload["poly_roots"];
lib=CreateLibrary[{"poly_roots.c"},"poly_roots","CompileOptions"->"-Ofast -fopenmp","Libraries"->{"gsl"}];
func1=LibraryFunctionLoad[lib,"roots",{{Real,1}},{Real,1}];
func2=LibraryFunctionLoad[lib,"modifiedRoots",{{Real,1}},{Real,1}];
gslRoots=func1//Compile[{{i,_Real,1}},#[i],RuntimeAttributes->{Listable},Parallelization->True]&;
gslModifiedRoots=func2//Compile[{{i,_Real,1}},#[i],RuntimeAttributes->{Listable},Parallelization->True]&;
rootsCounts=LibraryFunctionLoad[lib,"rootsCounts",{Integer,{Real,1},{Real,1}},{Integer,1}];

n=18;
{w,h}={10^3,10^3};
Dimensions[counts=rootsCounts[n,{-2,2,w},{-2,2,h}]]//AbsoluteTiming

With[{idx=Round[255 Rescale[N[counts UnitStep[Quantile[counts,0.999]-counts]]]]+1},
Part[Developer`ToPackedArray@Table[List@@ColorData["SunsetColors",i],{i,0.,1,1/255}],idx]
]//ArrayReshape[#,{w,h,3}]&//Image
```

C code (poly_roots.c):

```
#include "WolframLibrary.h"
#include <omp.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_poly.h>

void solve(int n, double *a, double *z)
{
    gsl_poly_complex_workspace *ws=gsl_poly_complex_workspace_alloc(n+1);
    gsl_poly_complex_solve(a,n+1,ws,z);
    gsl_poly_complex_workspace_free(ws);
}


// Note that the parameter list of the previous "roots" is reversed
DLLEXPORT int roots(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){
    MTensor in, out;
    in = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
    mreal *in_data = libData->MTensor_getRealData(in);
    mint n = libData->MTensor_getFlattenedLength(in);
    mint len = 2*(n - 1);
    double *z = malloc(len * sizeof(double));
    solve(n-1,in_data,z);
    int err = libData->MTensor_new( MType_Real, 1, &len, &out );
    mreal* out_data = libData->MTensor_getRealData(out);
    memcpy(out_data, z, len*sizeof(z));
    MArgument_setMTensor(Res,out);
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

DLLEXPORT int modifiedRoots(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res){
    MTensor in, out;
    in = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
    mreal *in_data = libData->MTensor_getRealData(in);
    mint n = libData->MTensor_getFlattenedLength(in);
    mint n1 = n + 1;
    mreal *a = malloc(n1*sizeof(mreal));
    memcpy(a, in_data, n1*sizeof(mreal));
    a[n]=1.0;
    mint len = 2*n;
    double *z = malloc(len * sizeof(double));
    solve(n,a,z);
    int err = libData->MTensor_new( MType_Real, 1, &len, &out );
    mreal* out_data = libData->MTensor_getRealData(out);
    memcpy(out_data, z, len*sizeof(z));
    MArgument_setMTensor(Res,out);
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}

DLLEXPORT int rootsCounts(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    MTensor out;
    mint n = MArgument_getInteger(Args[0]);
    
    MTensor T_arg1 = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[1]);
    mreal* xRange = libData->MTensor_getRealData(T_arg1);
    mreal x1 = xRange[0], x2 = xRange[1];
    int w = (int)xRange[2];

    MTensor T_arg2 = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[2]);
    mreal* yRange = libData->MTensor_getRealData(T_arg2);
    mreal y1 = yRange[0], y2 = yRange[1];
    int h = (int)yRange[2];
    
    mint len = w * h;
    int err = libData->MTensor_new( MType_Integer, 1, &len, &out );
    mint* out_data = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(out);
    double a[n+1], z[2*n];
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:a,z) 
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 1<<n; ii++) {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < n; jj++) {
            a[jj]=2*((ii >> jj) & 1)-1.0;
        }
        a[n]=1.0;
        solve(n,a,z);
        for (int k = 0; k < n; k++){
            double x=z[2*k];
            double y=z[2*k+1];
            int i = (w*(x - x1)/(x2 - x1));
            int j = (h*(y - y1)/(y2 - y1));
            if(0<i && i<w && 0<j && j<h )
                out_data[i+w*j]++;
        }
    }

    MArgument_setMTensor(Res,out);
    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}
```