# Drawing the roots of polynomials on the complex plane

Tags: plotting, polynomials

I have a polynomial $f(x)=x^2(x + 1)^{2n} + 2x^{n + 1}(x + 1)^n + x^{2n}$.

Then I want to show the roots of $f(x)$ from $2\leq n\leq 30$  in the complex plane. I have tried lots of methods but don't found one that worked.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73312/1871

Comment: You can type == to use Wolfram alpha and then type `Roots of` or `Roots` followed by the polynomial like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aQOP.png.  Among the summary of results, it shows the roots in the complex plane https://i.stack.imgur.com/47T4w.png .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, n_] := x^2 (x + 1)^(2 n) + 2 x^(n + 1) (x + 1)^n + x^(2 n);

Manipulate[
 ListPlot[
  Table[
   Tooltip[#, StringForm["n=``", n]] & /@ 
    ReIm[SolveValues[f[x, n] == 0, x] //
      N[#, 15] &],
   {n, int[[1]], int[[2]]}],
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {Re, Im}),
  PlotLegends -> PointLegend[Range @@ int,
    LegendLabel -> "n"],
  PlotLabel -> StringForm["Roots of ``", f[x, "n"]]],
 {{int, {2, 5}, "n interval"}, 2, 30, 1,
  ControlType -> IntervalSlider,
  Method -> "Push",
  MinIntervalSize -> 0,
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 5):

First, define your function:

```
 f[x_, n_] :=  x^2 (x + 1)^(2 n) + 2 x^(n + 1) (x + 1)^n + x^(2 n);
```

Then plot the roots of the function 0 == f[x,n] for various n:

```
 Manipulate[r = Roots[0 == f[x, n], x] // N; 
       ListPlot[ReIm[r[[All, 2]] //. Or -> List]], {n, 2, 30, 1}]
```

Here it is for n=21:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the title has the word `Complex` in it, I will present a minor variation using `ComplexListPlot`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
f[x_, n_] := x^2 (x + 1)^(2 n) + 2 x^(n + 1) (x + 1)^n + x^(2 n);

Manipulate[
 roots = x /. {ToRules[Roots[0 == f[x, n], x] // N]};
 Column[{
   "Roots of " <> ToString[TraditionalForm[f[x, n] == 0]],
   Spacer[10],
   ComplexListPlot[Tooltip[roots]
    , PlotStyle -> Directive[
      Red, AbsolutePointSize[6]
      ]
    , AspectRatio -> Automatic
    , PlotRange -> {{-13, 1}, {-6, 6}}
    , ImageSize -> 400
    , GridLines -> Automatic
    , GridLinesStyle -> {{Gray, Dotted}
      , {Gray, Dotted}
      }
    ]
   }
  , Alignment -> Center
  ]
 , {{n, 5}, 2, 31, 1}
 , ContentSize -> {460, 460}
 ]
```

[image]