# Speed up this computation involving NSolve many times?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, generative-art

Can you think of a way of speeding up this computation ? I don't.

```
n = 100000;
f[t1_, t2_] = 
  x^5*(x*(x*(x + I) + I) + I*(Exp[I*t2]*(Exp[I*t1]*(Exp[I*t2]*(-Exp[I*t2] + 1) + 1) - 1) - 
         1)) - I*x*(x*(x*(x - 1) - 1) + 1) + I*(Exp[I*t1]*(Exp[I*t1]*(Exp[I*t1]*(Exp[I*t2] - 1) - 1) + 1) - 1);
tlist = RandomReal[{0, 2 Pi}, {n, 2}];

data = Flatten[ParallelTable[ReIm[x /. NSolve[f @@ t == 0, {x}]], {t, tlist}], 1];
```

Why? To produce nice images!

```
ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.025], PointSize[0.001], Black},
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Reference: https://profconradi.github.io/category/matematica.html

Comment: How long does it take now?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau 23 seconds for `n=10000` on my PC

Comment: You're basically finding the roots of a polynomial in `x`, so you can use `Solve` rather than `NSolve`.  Doing so knocks about 15% off of the computer time on my machine; not a huge speed-up but not completely insignificant either.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Indeed, same speed-up observed on my PC, thanks.

Comment: This seems somewhat faster. `nsols = ParallelTable[{ToRules[NRoots[f @@ t == 0, x]]}, {t, tlist}];`. I get a bit under 3 seconds on my machine.

Comment: Maybe also relevant: https://numpi.dm.unipi.it/scientific-computing-libraries/mpsolve/

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit on what the underlying algorithm is? 
Is it simply roots of some family of polynomials? The image suggests some type of iteration/IFS...

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73312/1871

Comment: @PerAlexandersson The polynomial depends on parameters $(t_1,t_2)$. Each point corresponds to the roots of a polynomial for some random values of the parameters.

Answer (score 6):

Since this about polynomials in one complex variable, we can compute the eigenvalues of the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) instead. Since `Eigenvalues` is a bit slow on small matrices, I decided to use a `LibraryFunction`. For ease of use, I employ  the *Eigen* package for the eigensolve.

```
coeffs = Compile[{{t, _Real, 1}},
   With[{
     T1 = Exp[I Compile`GetElement[t, 1]],
     T2 = Exp[I Compile`GetElement[t, 2]]
     },
    {I (-1. + T1 (1. + T1 (-1. + T1 (-1. + T2)))), -I 1., I 1., 
     1. I, -1. I, 1. I (-1. + T2 (-1. + T1 (1. + (1. - T2) T2))), 
     1. I, 1. I, 1.}
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
   ];

Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
Quiet[LibraryFunctionUnload[cSolvePolynomial[8]]];
ClearAll[cSolvePolynomial];
cSolvePolynomial[d_] := 
  cSolvePolynomial[d] = Module[{lib, code, name}, name = "cf";
    code = StringJoin["

#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"

#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <Eigen/Eigenvalues>

static constexpr mint d = " <> IntegerString[d] <> ";

using Complex = std::complex<mreal>;

using Matrix_T = Eigen::Matrix<Complex,d,d>;
using Vector_T = Eigen::Matrix<Complex,d,1>;

    // Computes k-th job pointer for job_count equally sized jobs distributed on thread_count threads.
    template<typename Int, typename Int1, typename Int2>
    inline Int JobPointer( const Int job_count, const Int1 thread_count_, const Int2 thread_ )
    {
        const Int thread_count = static_cast<Int>(thread_count_);
        const Int thread       = static_cast<Int>(thread_);
        const Int chunk_size   = job_count / thread_count;
        const Int remainder    = job_count % thread_count;
        
        return chunk_size * thread + (remainder * thread) / thread_count;
    }


    // Executes the function `fun` of the form `[]( const Int thread ) -> void {...}` parallelized over `thread_count` threads.
    template<typename F, typename Int>
    inline void ParallelDo( F && fun, const Int thread_count )
    {
        if( thread_count <= static_cast<Int>(1) )
        {
            std::invoke( fun, static_cast<Int>(0) );
        }
        else
        {
            std::vector<std::future<void>> futures (thread_count);
            
            for( Int thread = 0; thread < thread_count; ++thread )
            {
                futures[thread] = std::async( std::forward<F>(fun), thread );
            }
            
            for( auto & future : futures )
            {
                future.get();
            }
        }
    }

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT int " <> name <> 
       "(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res)
{
    MTensor coeffs_      = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
    mint    thread_count = MArgument_getInteger(Args[1]);

    const mint n = libData->MTensor_getDimensions(coeffs_)[0];

    const Complex * const coeffs = reinterpret_cast<Complex*>(libData->MTensor_getComplexData(coeffs_));

    MTensor roots_;

    // Instead of a complex array of size n x d we allocate a real array of size (n * d) x 2.
    // This way, we can get rid of ReIm and Flatten.

    const mint dims [2] { n * d, 2 };

    (void)libData->MTensor_new( MType_Real, 2, &dims[0], &roots_ );

    Complex * roots = reinterpret_cast<Complex*>( libData->MTensor_getRealData(roots_));

    // This loops over all coefficient vectors and computes the eigenvalues of the companion matrix.

    ParallelDo(
        [roots,coeffs,n,thread_count]( const mint thread )
        {
            Eigen::ComplexEigenSolver<Matrix_T> S;
    
            Matrix_T C;
    
            C.setZero();
        
            for( int i = 0; i < d-1; ++i )
            {
                C(i+1,i) = Complex { 1., 0. };
            }
    
            const mint k_begin = JobPointer( n, thread_count, thread     );
            const mint k_end   = JobPointer( n, thread_count, thread + 1 );
    
            for( mint k = k_begin; k < k_end; ++k )
            {
                const Complex * const c = &coeffs[(d+1) * k];
                      Complex * const r = &roots [ d    * k];
        
                const Complex factor = - 1. / c[d];
        
                for( int i = 0; i < d; ++i )
                {
                    C(i,d-1) = c[i] * factor;
                }
        
                S.compute(C);
        
                Vector_T eigs = S.eigenvalues().col(0);
        
                for( int i = 0; i < d; ++i )
                {
                    r[i] = eigs(i);
                }
            }
        },
        thread_count
    );

 
    MArgument_setMTensor(Res, roots_);

    return LIBRARY_NO_ERROR;
}"];
    lib = 
     CreateLibrary[code, name, "Language" -> "C++", 
      "CompileOptions" -> {"-O3", "-std=c++20", "-pthread"}, 
      "IncludeDirectories" -> {"/opt/homebrew/include/eigen3"}, 
      "ShellOutputFunction" -> (If[# =!= "", Print[#]] &)];
    LibraryFunctionLoad[lib, 
     name, {{Complex, 2, "Constant"}, Integer}, {Real, 2}]
    ];
```

Here an usage example :

```
degree = 8;
threadCount = 8;
cf = cSolvePolynomial[degree];
data2 = cf[coeffs[tlist], threadCount]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.238111

On my machine, OP's code takes `52.2739` seconds instead. So this is a **220-fold speedup**.

Correctness can be checked with

```
Max[Abs[(Sort /@ Partition[data, 8]) - (Sort /@ Partition[data2, 8])]]
```

> 1.05471*10^-14

This allows me to run this with ten times the number of points and to get this pictures:

[image]

And here with 8000000 random points:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
data1 = Flatten[Table[ReIm[x /. NSolve[f @@ t == 0, {x}]], {t, tlist}], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*    51.9531    *)
```

Optimizing @DanielLichtblau's comment a bit, and using $s_k=e^{i t_k}$:

```
g[s1_, s2_] = Series[f[t1, t2] /. {E^(I t1) -> s1, E^(I t2) -> s2},
                {x, 0, 8}] // FullSimplify // Normal
(*    I (-1 + s1 + s1^2 (-1 + s1 (-1 + s2))) - I x + I x^2 + I x^3 - I x^4 +
      I (-1 + s2 (-1 + s1 (1 + s2 - s2^2))) x^5 + I x^6 + I x^7 + x^8    *)

data2 = ReIm[List @@ Join @@ Map[NRoots[g @@ #, x] &, Exp[I*tlist]][[All, All, 2]]]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
(*    3.71658    *)
```

is faster by a factor of 14, and numerically indistinguishable:

```
data2 - data1 // Norm
(*    5.06198*10^-14    *)
```

Replacing `Map` by `ParallelMap` gives a small speedup, but not much.

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is the [Ehrlich-Aberth algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberth_method#) which is easy to implement:

```
cAberth = Block[{z, t, x},
  With[{
    \[Epsilon] = 16. $MachineEpsilon,
    d = 8,
    rCode = N[
       Divide[
         f[Compile`GetElement[t, 1], Compile`GetElement[t, 2]], 
         D[f[Compile`GetElement[t, 1], Compile`GetElement[t, 2]], x]
         ] /. x -> z]
    },
   Compile[{{t, _Real, 1}},
    Block[{z, w, sum, maxw, r, zlist, wlist},
     zlist = RandomComplex[{-1 - I, 1 + I}, d];
     z = 0. + 0. I;
     r = 0. + 0. I;
     maxw = 1.;
     
     While[ maxw > \[Epsilon],
      
      maxw = 0.;
      
      Do[
       z = Compile`GetElement[zlist, i];
       r = rCode;
       sum = 0. + 0. I;
       Do[sum += 1./(z - Compile`GetElement[zlist, j]), {j, 1, i - 1}];
       Do[sum += 1./(z - Compile`GetElement[zlist, j]), {j, i + 1, d}];
       w = r /(1. - r sum);
       maxw = Max[maxw, Abs[w]];
       zlist[[i]] -= w;
       
       , {i, 1, d}];
      ];
     zlist
     ],
    CompilationTarget -> "C",
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True,
    RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
    ]
   ]
  ];
```

Use it like this on you problem:

```
data3 = Flatten[ReIm[cAberth[tlist]], 1];
```

This is a quick and dirty implementation of the "Gauss-Seidel"-like variant as mentioned in the text. I just generate random starting values without looking at the actual coefficients; so this should definitely be improved.

It takes about 25% longer than `SolvePolynomial[degree][coeffs[tlist], threadCount]` from my other answer. But I think that is due to the parallelization in `CompiledFunction`s; that is sometimes a bit poor. I expect that a corresponding *LibraryLink* implementation with parallelization within the function would perform better.

Comment: Consider posting an answer here?: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73312/1871 :)