# How to plot a surface given implicitly by 3 equations in 5 coordinate variables?

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, implicit, parameters

I have 3 implicit equations in 5 variables: $f_1(S, y_h, y_d, x_h, J)=0$, $f_2(S, y_h, y_d, x_h, J)=0$, and $f_3(S, y_h, y_d, x_h, J)=0$. These equations determine a 3D surface in $S-y_h-y_d$ coordinate system. The equations are given below.

```
M = 1;
roo = 0.01;
xd = 3;

f1[S_, yh_, yd_, xh_, J_]:= 2 M (xh^2 - (yh + 1)^2)/(xh^2 + (yh + 1)^2)^2 + 
  2 S ((xh - xd)^2 - (yh + yd)^2)/((xh - xd)^2 + (yh + yd)^2)^2 + 
  J/(2 yh) == 0,

f2[S_, yh_, yd_, xh_, J_]:= M*xh (yh + 1)/(xh^2 + (yh + 1)^2)^2 + 
  S (xh - xd) (yh + yd)/((xh - xd)^2 + (yh + yd)^2)^2 == 0,

f3[S_, yh_, yd_, xh_, J_]:= J*Log[2 yh*J/roo] + 2 M (yh + 1)/(xh^2 + (yh + 1)^2) + 
  2 S (yh + yd)/((xh - xd)^2 + (yh + yd)^2) - (Log[2/roo] + 1) == 0,
```

where $S, y_h, y_d, x_h, J$ are `Reals`, $yh>0$, and $yd>0$.

I am trying to obtain the surface in the $S-yh-yd$ coordinate system like the following image. How to plot it?
[image]

What I have tried: For 1 equation in 3 variables: $f(S, y_h, y_d) = 0$, I can use `ContourPlot3D` to get the surface; For equations expressed in an explicit form: $S = S(x_h, J)$, $y_h = y_h(x_h, J)$, $y_d = y_d(x_h, J)$, I can use `ParametricPlot3D`. But I failed when I faced this issue introduced above. Please help me. Thanks a lot for your support!

### Background Information

This problem is from the paper [*Prominence eruptions and coronal mass ejections triggered by newly emerging flux* by *J. Lin, T. G. Forbes, P. A. Isenberg*](https://doi.org/10.1029/2001JA000046).

Comment: Please define the three functions `{f1, f2, f3}` in terms of `{x, y, x, a, b}`.

Comment: What's the range of those variables, especially `xh`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I changed the statement of the question. Please find the definition of functions in the code. @bbgodfrey

Comment: Thank you for your attention. *S, yh, yd, xh, J* are Reals, *yh*>0, and *yd*>0. *xh* can be negative, zero, or positive. @xzczd

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is more involved than I thought.

This post involves several code blocks, you can copy them easily with the help of [`importCode`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3537/1871).

Based on [Ulrich Neumann's idea](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/295582/1871) i.e. transforming the $(x_h, y_h, y_d)$ coordinates to $(S,y_h,y_d)$ coordinates, we transform the contour surface directly as follows:

```
M = 1;
roo = 0.01;
xd = 3;
sys = {(2 M (xh^2 - (yh + 1)^2))/(xh^2 + (yh + 1)^2)^2 + (
        2 S ((xh - xd)^2 - (yh + yd)^2))/((xh - xd)^2 + (yh + yd)^2)^2 + J/(2 yh) == 0, 
       (M xh (yh + 1))/(xh^2 + (yh + 1)^2)^2 + (
        S (xh - xd) (yh + yd))/((xh - xd)^2 + (yh + yd)^2)^2 == 0, 
       J Log[(2 yh J)/roo] + (2 M (yh + 1))/(xh^2 + (yh + 1)^2) + (
        2 S (yh + yd))/((xh - xd)^2 + (yh + yd)^2) == Log[2/roo] + 1};

ruleJS = Solve[sys // Most, {J, S}] // Flatten;

eqmid = sys[[3]] /. ruleJS;

Sfunc[xh_, yh_, yd_] = S /. ruleJS;

plot = ContourPlot3D[
      0 == Subtract @@ eqmid // Evaluate, 
      {xh, -5/2, 7/2}, {yh, 0, 4}, {yd, 0, 6}, 
       PlotPoints -> 20]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {208.254, …} *)

Show[plot /. 
    GraphicsComplex[lst_, rest__] :> 
      GraphicsComplex[
        Function[{xh, yh, yd}, {Sfunc[xh, yh, yd], yh, yd}] @@ 
            Transpose@lst // Transpose, rest], 
  AxesLabel -> {S, Subscript[y, h], Subscript[y, d]}, 
 ViewPoint -> {1.2, 0.7, -3.}, ViewVertical -> {-1, 1, 1}, 
 BoxRatios -> Automatic, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 3/2}, {0, 4}, {0, 6}}]
```

[image]

> **Remark**
>
> The equation has been defined in a strange manner i.e. `0 == Subtract @@ eqmid` to circumvent the following bug:
>
> [ContourPlot3D wrong plotting result with extra surfaces](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275930/1871)
>
> Do notice this work-around is not robust. Personally I recommend
> turning back to a earlier version like *v8* or *v9* to circumvent the
> bug. The following is the output in *v8*:
>
> [image]
>
> As we can see, the surface is plotted better.

If you just want to know how to plot the surface, you can stop here.

---

### Further Analysis

If you carefully compare the plot in the paper to ours, you may notice that, the surface in the region `yd < 3 && yh < 2 && s > 0.5` seems to be slightly inconsistent (even if we ignore the roughness of the result in paper). I **suspect** the surface in the paper hasn't been plotted in a correct way.

The following is a way to produce a contour surface that's closer to that in paper. The idea itself is simple: we directly eliminate the redundant `J` and `xh`, and plot the remaining equation. `J` is easy to eliminate, because the first equation is a linear equation of `J`, so it can be `Solve`d easily:

```
rule1 = Solve[sys[[1]], J] // Flatten
```

The troublesome part is `xh`. We can obtain a 5th order polynomial equation of `xh` by taking numerator of `sys[[2]]`, but as mentioned in the question, `xh∈Reals`, so only one of the real root is needed. Which real root should be chosen? Additionally, how can this be done in an efficient way?

To speed up the code, I'll turn to the function `roots` in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/73532/1871):

```
roots[c_List] := Block[{a}, a = DiagonalMatrix[ConstantArray[1., Length@c - 2], -1];
   a[[1]] = -Rest@c/First@c;
   Eigenvalues[a]];
```

*I haven't used the more efficient method based on librarylink mentioned therein because <strike>I'm too lazy</strike> I don't want to make this answer too advanced.*

With `roots`, we build the following function for solving `xh`:

```
takenume = (Subtract@@#//Together//Numerator)&;
(xhfunc[S_, yh_, yd_?NumericQ] := First@Sort@Cases[Chop@roots[#], _Real]) &@
 Reverse@CoefficientList[takenume@sys[[2]], xh]
```

Here I've simply chosen the smallest `Real` root of the equation. This is merely a guess. But later we'll see this guess indeed reproduces the picture in paper.

By substituting `J` and `xh` to last equation, we obtain an equation that can be plotted by `ContourPlot3D`. To improve the efficiency, we `Compile` the obtained equation:

```
lhs3compiled = 
  Compile[{S, yh, yd, xh}, 
   sys[[3]] /. rule1 // Subtract@@#& // Evaluate, 
   RuntimeOptions -> EvaluateSymbolically -> False];
```

And we write the following code for visualization:

```
(* The minus sign is for circumventing the aforementioned bug. *)
ContourPlot3D[
  -lhs3compiled[S, yh, yd, xhfunc[S, yh, yd]], 
  {S, -1, 3/2}, {yh, 0, 4}, {yd, 0, 6}, Contours -> {0}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, BoxRatios -> Automatic,
  ViewPoint -> {1.2, 0.7, -3.}, ViewVertical -> {-1, 1, 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

As we can see, the surface in the region `yd < 3 && yh < 2 && s > 0.5` is closer to the one in the paper, but this is **probably** the result of numeric error. Let's take a slice and observe at `S = 3/2`:

```
With[{S = 3/2}, Plot3D[
      lhs3compiled[S, yh, yd, xhfunc[S, yh, yd]], {yd, 0, 6}, {yh, 0, 4}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic, PlotRange -> All, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Automatic}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &},
   PlotPoints -> 50]]
```

[image]

As shown above, there's a sudden jump at the region `yd < 3 && yh < 2`, and the zero contour actually lies on the *cliff wall*. Further check suggests the *cliff* is generated by `xhfunc`, which involves the artificial "take the smallest real root" operation that's likely to generate jump in solution:

```
With[{S = 3/2}, Plot3D[
      xhfunc[S, yh, yd], {yd, 0, 6}, {yh, 0, 4}, AxesLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotRange -> All, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Automatic}, Mesh -> {{1}}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, PlotPoints -> 50]]
```

[image]

```
With[{S = 3/2}, ContourPlot[
    {0 == lhs3compiled[S, yh, yd, xhfunc[S, yh, yd]], 
   xhfunc[S, yh, yd] == 1}, {yd, 0, 6}, {yh, 0, 4}, FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
  PlotPoints -> 50, ScalingFunctions -> {"Reverse", Automatic}]]
```

[image]

Of course, the illustration above is inadequate to prove the new surface is fake, but I think it's at least plausible.

Comment: Nice! It's unfortunate that this (fairly general) bug persists through 5 versions of mathematica! Not to mention the time it takes to get the wrong answer.

Comment: I truly appreciate your response! This surface was plotted in a paper published in 2001, but the author forgot the details about the Mathematica code. Your code brilliantly addresses this issue.  I am currently trying to grasp more details of your code. Additionally, I am curious about the outcomes if we choose different real roots (not just the smallest one). Would the parametric surface exhibit significant changes? Once again, thank you sincerely for your time and invaluable contribution.

Comment: @xzczd Thank your for your updates. I guess there might be additional constraints that exclude the other real roots. As you mentioned, I need a better understanding of this model. If I use your method for plotting in my paper, should I include a citation, acknowledge your contribution in the text, or list you as a co-author?

Comment: @yuhaochen Directly citing the web page is a possible choice. (BTW this has been discussing in meta but there's no conclusion so far 囧: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/968/1871 )

Comment: @yuhaochen After a more careful analyse, I believe the surface generated by coordinate transformation is the only valid surface. See my revised answer.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, I'm a little bit late, perhaps I found an easier solution

```
M = 1;
roo = 0.01;
xd = 3;

f1[S_, yh_, yd_, xh_, J_] := 
 2 M (xh^2 - (yh + 1)^2)/(xh^2 + (yh + 1)^2)^2 + 
  2 S ((xh - xd)^2 - (yh + yd)^2)/((xh - xd)^2 + (yh + yd)^2)^2 + 
  J/(2 yh) ; 
f2[S_, yh_, yd_, xh_, J_] := 
 M*xh (yh + 1)/(xh^2 + (yh + 1)^2)^2 + 
  S (xh - xd) (yh + yd)/((xh - xd)^2 + (yh + yd)^2)^2  ; 
f3[S_, yh_, yd_, xh_, J_] := 
 J*Log[2 yh*J/roo] + 2 M (yh + 1)/(xh^2 + (yh + 1)^2) + 
  2 S (yh + yd)/((xh - xd)^2 + (yh + yd)^2) - (Log[2/roo] + 1)
```

First eliminate `J,S`

```
solJS = Solve[{f1[S, yh, yd, xh, J], f2[S, yh, yd, xh, J]}==0, {J,S}][[1]]
```

From

```
Map[FunctionDomain[#, {yh, yd, xh}] &, solJS[[All, 2]]]
(*{xh != 3 && yd + yh != 0 && xh^2 + 2 yh + yh^2 != -1, 
xh != 3 && yd + yh != 0 && xh^2 + 2 yh + yh^2 != -1}*)
```

we conclude `xh<3`!

One equation `eq[ yh, yd, xh]` remains

Now we plot `ContourPlot3D` this equation and memorize `S` in the colorfunction

```
    eq =0== f3[S, yh, yd, xh, J] /. solJS 
 pic4D = ContourPlot3D[
  Evaluate[eq], {yh, 0, 5}, {yd, 0, 5}, {xh, -5, 3-.001}, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{yh, yd, xh}, Evaluate[S /. solJS]], 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False]
```

[image]

From this plot we take the point and color values

```
pts = pic4D[[1, 1]][[1]];
cols = pic4D[[1, 1]][[3, 2]];
```

and collect the 4D solution points `S,yh,yd,xh`

```
Syhydxh  = MapThread[Join[{#2},#1 ] &, {pts, cols}];
```

Plot subspace `S,yh,yd`

```
Graphics3D[{Map[{Hue[#[[-1]]], Point[ # [[{ 1, 2, 3}]]]} &, 
Syhydxh ] }, PlotRange -> {{-1, 3/2}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}}, 
AxesLabel -> {S, yh , yd}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Unfortunately I couldn't compare my result with xzcdz`s result because Mathematica v12.2 doesn't evaluate his answer.

Hope it helps!

**addendum**

Complete solution

```
SyhydxhJ = Map[Join[#,{J /. solJS /. {yh -> #[[2]], yd -> #[[3]], xh-> #[[4]]}} ] &, Syhydxh ];
```

fullfills the three equations quite well

```
null = Map[ {Apply[f1, #]  , Apply[f2, #]  , Apply[f3, #]  } &,SyhydxhJ]
```

[image]

**2. addendum**

Comparing with xzczd's answer we see a very good match(without  "oh no" part)

[image]

Comment: Sadly [that bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275930/1871) has influenced this solution, too. In v8 the `pic4D` looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqlgm.png `ContourPlot3D` simply cannot be used in any step if we want to resolve the problem in higher versions, I'm afraid.

Comment: @xzxzd Thanks for your comment. I added `pic4D` in my answer. Meanwhile I could evaluate your answer and got good agreement

Comment: @xzxzd The branch you signed with "oh no"  doesn't occur in my solution

Comment: Yeah but a redundant "triangle" appears instead...

Comment: BTW, you don't need to extract the points, just transform the coordinates in the first argument of `GraphicsComplex`, then you'll obtain the transformed surface.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann Really appreciate your answer, which provides a new perspective on solving this problem.

Comment: @xzczd I am not familiar with `GraphicsComplex`. I am wondering how to transform these points into a surface?

Comment: I just realize something really funny: with `lhs=f3[S, yh, yd, xh, J] /. solJS `, compare `ContourPlot3D[
   lhs == 0, {yh, 0, 5}, {yd, 0, 5}, {xh, -5, 5}]` and `ContourPlot3D[
   0 == lhs, {yh, 0, 5}, {yd, 0, 5}, {xh, -5, 5}]`

Comment: @xzczd Astonishing! Though the correct use of `ContourPlot3D` should be `ContourPlot3D[lhs , {yh, 0, 5}, {yd, 0, 5}, {xh, -5, 5}, 
 Contours -> {0}]` ???

Comment: `lhs == 0` and `0==lhs` are valid nowadays, of course. But in version 5 or earlier, when `ContourPlot3D` is still inside a official package, `ContourPlot3D[lhs , ……,   Contours -> {0}]` is indeed the only valid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Here I present an alternative solution which uses `NSolve` to get all real solution points `S,yh,yd,xh` of the underlying problem.

```
M = 1;
roo = 1/100;
xd = 3;

f1[S_, yh_, yd_, xh_, J_] := 
  2 M (xh^2 - (yh + 1)^2)/(xh^2 + (yh + 1)^2)^2 + 
   2 S ((xh - xd)^2 - (yh + yd)^2)/((xh - xd)^2 + (yh + yd)^2)^2 + 
   J/(2 yh);
f2[S_, yh_, yd_, xh_, J_] := 
  M*xh (yh + 1)/(xh^2 + (yh + 1)^2)^2 + 
   S (xh - xd) (yh + yd)/((xh - xd)^2 + (yh + yd)^2)^2;
f3[S_, yh_, yd_, xh_, J_] := 
 J*Log[2 yh*J/roo] + 2 M (yh + 1)/(xh^2 + (yh + 1)^2) + 
  2 S (yh + yd)/((xh - xd)^2 + (yh + yd)^2) - (Log[2/roo] + 1)

solJS = Solve[{f1[S, yh, yd, xh, J], f2[S, yh, yd, xh, J]} == 0, {J,S}][[1]]
```

Find all real solutions of `f3==0`

```
solxh[yh_, yd_] :=Values@NSolve[{0 == f3[S, yh, yd, xh, J] /. solJS, -5 < xh < 3}, xh,Reals] // Flatten

zwsol = Table[zw = solxh[yh, yd];Map[ {S /. solJS, yh, yd, xh} /. xh -> # &, zw], {yh, Subdivide[1/100, 5, 50]}, {yd,Subdivide[1/100, 5, 50]}];// AbsoluteTiming (*271seconds*)
```

All solution quadrupels `S,yh,yd,xh`

```
SyhydxhN = zwsol /. {} -> Nothing // Flatten[#, 2] &;   
Graphics3D[{ Map[{Hue[#[[3]]], Point[Most[#]]} &, SyhydxhN ]}, 
PlotRange -> {{-1, 3/2}, {0, 5}, {0, 5}}, AxesLabel -> {S, yh, yd},Axes -> True]
```

[image]

comparing with xzczd's solution (sorry,in v12.2 I couldn't exclude the "oh no"-surfaces)

[image]

conclusion:

If `NSolve`-result is correct,

- the solution covers a smaller surface than that found by xzczd
- a slightly different solution found with `ContourPlot3D` in my first answer

Comment: @xzxzd I checked my code, it runs fine in a fresh kernel on Mathematica v12.2

Comment: Ah, I see the issue. I've tested the `solxh` outside of `Table`, so the `yh` and `yd` are not successfully passed into `solJS`. (I'd suggest define the function as e.g. `mid[yh_, yd_] = 0 == f3[S, yh, yd, xh, J] /. solJS; solxh[yh_, yd_] := Values@NSolve[{mid[yh, yd], -5 < xh < 3}, xh, Reals] // Flatten` to make it more robust. )

Comment: @xzczd I am curious what could be the reason for the different solution-surfaces

Comment: Your solution is more plausible, I should say, because replacing `NSolve` with `Solve` results in the same solution, and `Solve` is usually quite robust. But I can't think out a way to analyze deeper at the moment...

Comment: @xzczd Perhaps you could take all the points from your plot "extra surfaces" and check wether they fullfill the three equations?

Comment: @xzczd Thanks for your reply. I would like to plot the surface of the solution point cloud `S,yh,yd `, but didn't succeed. I tried `ListContourPlot3D` and `ListSurfacePlot3D`. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Join the point to a surface is just not easy. The performance issue of `ListSurfacePlot3D` is a long standing problem. (Just search in this site. ) The performance of `ListContourPlot3D` is also not great AFAIK. I've just finished revising my answer, have a look.