# How to refine ContourPlot3D result?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, precision-and-accuracy

From this interesting question  [How to plot a surface given implicitly by 3 equations in 5 coordinate variables?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/295509/how-to-plot-a-surface-given-implicitly-by-3-equations-in-5-coordinate-variables/295693?noredirect=1#comment732124_295693) I have found a subproblem that I would like to clarify:

Often it is advantageous to use `ContourPlot3D` to solve (visualize) an equation `eq[yh,yd,xh]==0`

```
eq = 0 == -1 + (2 (1 + yh))/(xh^2 + (1 + yh)^2) - (
   2 xh (1 + yh) ((-3 + xh)^2 + (yd + yh)^2))/((-3 + 
      xh) (xh^2 + (1 + yh)^2)^2) - 
   Log[200] - (4 yh (-9 xh + 6 xh^2 - xh^3 + 3 yd - xh yd - 
        3 xh^2 yd + xh^3 yd + xh yd^2 + 3 yh - 10 xh yh + 3 xh^2 yh + 
        6 yd yh + xh yd^2 yh + 6 yh^2 - xh yh^2 + 3 yd yh^2 + 
        xh yd yh^2 + 
        3 yh^3) Log[-((800 yh^2 (-9 xh + 6 xh^2 - xh^3 + 3 yd - 
              xh yd - 3 xh^2 yd + xh^3 yd + xh yd^2 + 3 yh - 
              10 xh yh + 3 xh^2 yh + 6 yd yh + xh yd^2 yh + 6 yh^2 - 
              xh yh^2 + 3 yd yh^2 + xh yd yh^2 + 3 yh^3))/((-3 + 
              xh) (yd + yh) (1 + xh^2 + 2 yh + yh^2)^2))])/((-3 + 
        xh) (yd + yh) (1 + xh^2 + 2 yh + yh^2)^2)
```

`ContourPlot3D` shows a smooth solution surface

```
pic = ContourPlot3D[
Evaluate[ eq ] , {yh, 0, 5}, {yd, 0, 5}, {xh, -2.5, 3 - .01}, 
ColorFunctionScaling -> False (*MaxRecursion\[Rule]4*) , 
Mesh -> False , PerformanceGoal -> "Quality" ] 

pts = pic[[1, 1]][[1]]; (* save points from pic*)
```

[image]

But checking the solution subsequently

```
ptsF = Select[pts, ! (eq /. Equal -> Subtract /. {yh -> #[[1]], yd -> #[[2]],xh -> #[[3]]})^2 < .01 &];
Show[{pic , ListPointPlot3D[ptsF, PlotStyle -> Red]},AxesLabel -> {yh, yd, xh}]
```

[image]

shows parts (red points) in the solution surface where `eq==0` isn't fullfilled. (To be precise, the squared residual error in the red zone is larger than `0.01`. )

I know how to improve the quality of `ContourPlot3D` using options `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion` but the basic problem remains.

My question:

How can I force better results from `ContourPlot3D`?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want to make the "solution" found by `ContourPlot3D` numerically accurate?

Comment: @xzczd Yes I am looking for a numerical improvement

Answer (score 6):

First of all, it's worth pointing out that, setting a larger `PlotPoints` or `MaxRecursion` i.e. using more points for visualization improves not only the visualization, but also the numerical accuracy, it's just rather inefficient. And if we don't consider increasing plot points as a choice, then it's not possible to improve the numerical accuracy by adjusting option of `ContourPlot3D` AFAIK. (I sincerely hope I'm wrong. ) I think it's reasonable: `ContourPlot3D` is just for visualization, so the points used for creating the surface only need to be **visually** accurate i.e. it's not necessary to make the "solution" for visualization strictly fullfill the plotted equation.

Still, it's possible to improve the "solution" found by `ContourPlot3D`. The idea is simple: we solve `eq` with `FindRoot`, using points in `pic` as initial guesses.

The code is as follows. Definition of `eq` is the same as yours.

```
(* Modify pic slightly for better illustration. *)
pic = ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[eq], {yh, 0, 5}, {yd, 0, 5}, {xh, -2.5, 3 - .01}, 
  Mesh -> False, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.5]]

eqfunc[yh_, yd_, xh_] = eq;
(* More general definition for pts, compatible with earlier versions. *)
pts = Cases[pic, GraphicsComplex[a_, __] :> a, ∞][[1]];

ClearAll@calibrate;
calibrate[yh_, yd_, xh_] := {yh, yd, xhvar} /. 
  FindRoot[eqfunc[yh, yd, xhvar], {xhvar, xh}]
ptsbetter = calibrate @@@ pts; // AbsoluteTiming
(* There'll be some warnings, don't worry. *)
(* {29.324, Null} *)
picbetter = pic /. pts -> ptsbetter
```

[image]

`FindRoot` spits out warnings, and the `picbetter` is visually the same as `pic`. Is `ptsbetter` really improved? Let's check the error:

```
error = ptsbetter\[Transpose] // Apply@eqfunc // Last // Abs // Sort;

error[[-10 ;;]]
(* {0.0859047, 0.0859366, 0.106304, 0.108949, 0.119662, 
    0.120376,  0.13304,   0.319378, 0.355189, 0.361554} *)

thre = Function@Evaluate@Simplify`PWToUnitStep@PiecewiseExpand@If[# > 0.01, 1, 0]

picadd = ListPointPlot3D[Pick[ptsbetter, thre@error, 1]];

picbetter~Show~picadd
```

[image]

Blue points are those whose absolute residual error are larger than `0.01`. (Notice I haven't added the `^2` i.e. this is amount to setting `<.0001` in your code. ) As we can see, Accuracy of `ptsbetter` is indeed better.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, very helpful. Actual I`m  trying to improve the surface "in normal direction" but still didn't succeed

Answer (score 3):

Similar to xzczd's helpful answer it's indead possible to improve the accuracy of the solution points found by `ContourPlot3D`

For this we use the knowledge of `VertexNormals` vn given by `ContourPlot3D` and try to improve the solution in this direction.

```
eqfunc[yh_, yd_, xh_] = eq; 
vn = Cases[pic, 
GraphicsComplex[__, VertexNormals -> q_] :> q, -1][[1]];

improve[ p_, n_] :=p + alfa n /. FindRoot[Apply[eqfunc, p + alfa n], {alfa, 0}]
ptsN = MapThread[ improve[#1 , #2 ] &, {pts, vn}, 1]; // Quiet (* new points *)
```

Surprisingly no  "red points" left

```
ptsF = Select[ptsN, ! (eq /. Equal -> Subtract /. {yh -> #[[1]], yd ->#[[2]], xh -> #[[3]]})^2 < .01 &];
(* {} *)
```

All new points `ptsN` fullfill the equation accurately

```
eqo = eq /. Equal -> Subtract;
Map[eqo /. {yh -> #[[1]], yd -> #[[2]], xh -> #[[3]]} &,ptsN] // MinMax
(*{-7.65864*10^-10, 4.83533*10^-11}*)
```